# Search functionality for child components from parent text box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a SideBar component that has a sub component called SideBarLink which directs to the correct page.

I am trying add search functionality to my sidebar with a text field.

I have added a text input to the SideBar component and I am trying to figure out the best way to hide the SideBarLink components based on the match between the search text and text prop of the SideBarLink.

This is my current design for the side bar but it feels ugly to declare the hidden event on every SideBarLink when we already know the text prop (especially when I start adding many more links).

```
import "./SideBar.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SideBarDropdown from "./SideBarDropdown";
import SideBarLink from "./SideBarLink";
import { TextInput } from "../Input";

const SideBar: React.FC = () => {
  const [searchPhrase, setSearchPhrase] = useState<string>();

  const acroynym = (str: string) =>
    str
      .split(/\s/)
      .reduce((response, word) => (response += word.slice(0, 1)), "");

  const match = (text: string) =>
    searchPhrase
      ? text.toLowerCase().includes(searchPhrase?.toLowerCase()) ||
        acroynym(text).toLowerCase().includes(searchPhrase?.toLowerCase())
      : true;

  return (
    <nav id="sidebar" className="custom_scrollbar">
      <ul className="list-unstyled components">
        <TextInput
          value={searchPhrase}
          onChange={(value: string) => setSearchPhrase(value!)}
        />
          <SideBarLink
            to={`${urls.accounts}`}
            text="Account"
            icon="fas fa-plus-square"
            hidden={!match("Account")}
          />
          <SideBarLink
            to={`${urls.customers}`}
            text="Customer"
            icon="fas fa-plus-square"
            hidden={!match("Customer")}
          />
          <SideBarLink
            to={`${urls.orders}`}
            text="Order"
            icon="fas fa-plus-square"
            hidden={!match("Order")}
          />
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

Is this the best approach for updating all the child components?

Comment: As an alternative you could have an array of objects representing the props for the link components (with text and urls fields for example), to which you apply the search filter and then map to your SiderBarLink component. This may also make it clearer for the reader of your code that there is a filter being applied on the JSX output and avoids your SiderBarLink component to mount and output null or render hidden dom elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick & dirty way, just pass the search text to the SideBarLink & declare your isMatch function there (you should also consider memoizing your function so it doesn't get redeclared after every render)

But I don't like this approach, because your SideBarLink being shown or not, has nothing to do with the SideBarLink itself. it's part of the rendering logic in your sidebar component so it should stay there.
in order to do that just define all your links in an array & just map over it. like this:

```
const links = useMemo(() => [
    { text: 'Account', to: `${urls.accounts}`, icon: 'fas fa-plus-square' },
    { text: 'Customer', to: `${urls.customers}`, icon: 'fas fa-plus-square' },
  ], []);
```

then in your render loop over the array:

```
   {links.map(({ text, to, icon }) => (
    <SideBarLink
      text="Customer"
      to={`${urls.customers}`}
      icon="fas fa-plus-square"
      isMatch={isMatch(text)}
    />
  ))}
```

also don't forget to memoize your isMatch function:

```
 const isMatch = useCallback(
    (text: string) =>
      searchPhrase
        ? text.toLowerCase().includes(searchPhrase?.toLowerCase()) ||
          acroynym(text).toLowerCase().includes(searchPhrase?.toLowerCase())
        : true,
    [searchPhrase],
  );
```

Comment: This is the solution I went for in the end. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped, but one other thing I missed & just noticed & edited in the answer is passing an empty array to your link's useMemo hook (in the previous version useMemo wasn't doing anything). you can alternatively remove your array definition from the hook inside your component & put it in a variable outside your react component, so there would be only one instance of it in your app (but I prefer the current aproach because you are not making global what is only needed in one place, but at the end if the day, both approach are fine in my opinion)